# developing solutions based on SharePoint 2013 Preview

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to developing SP solutions based on SharePoint 2013 Preview.
I Get SharePoint is not installed when running Visual Studio 2012[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as SharePoint 2013 Preview is just an earlier version of SharePoint but still deploy and register itself nearly like the RTM bits (at least for VS recognition, there is no changes).

- Make sure that your installation of SharePoint is working as expected. You must be able to connect to the central administration and the relevant services must be running.
- Make sure that you add the office tools to your VS2012 setup : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps
- Make sure that the registry key indicating the SP2013 is installed is present

[image: ensure SP2013 installation registry settings is present]

Anyway, you should grab some RTM binaries, if you need to do anything serious, that's pointless to suffer for the CTP issues since the final bits are available (unless you don't have access to an MSDN account of course).

Comment: Hi! i Can connect to central administration everything works fine plus sharepoint are in my registry , i am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 so i cant use the web installer to install VS office devop tool for vs preview , so what do i do know ?

Comment: you do have a version for the RTM edition of VS2012. I installed it recently, check out on the page they link both the preview & rtm (although the later one is more emphasized)